# How to hide Button by its value in js?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

How to hide button by its value ?

example :

```
<button class="mat-raised-button mat-primary" color="primary" mat-raised-button="">
    <span class="mat-button-wrapper">RESET</span>
    <div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple=""></div>
    <div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div>
</button>
```

Actually i want to hide this button having RESET. but i am not able to hide this with help of its Class because this same class are using in other buttons. If try to hide with class name all buttons will be hidden which having same class.

Any help ?

Comment: can you use css for this

Comment: yes. i can use css also

Comment: So you want to hide that button?

Comment: yes. Both css and JS is fine. Is there anyway ?

Comment: You shouldn't have divs inside button, what is the purpose of having them?

Comment: @RajeebbinRazaq, Is this example solve your issue https://codepen.io/manmur/pen/rNNbjXV   ??

Comment: One of the greatest thing in Angular is binding. Why are not using it with an *ngIf to do that?

Comment: @ManirajMurugan i tried to log all "button span" but i can see only one in my console.

Comment: @RajeebbinRazaq, Did you add all the buttons to the ```HTML```?? If so edit the codepen and send me of what you have tried in the above codepen..

Answer (score 0):

First your question is unclear , I cannot understand very good, what exactly you want to do and how you will do it. If you use JS , use keyword 'this' , 'this' will act for cuurent scope of triggered event of the button.

Example:

```
document.querySelector('button class').on('click', function() { 

   this.el.style.display = 'none'

});
```

Of course, inside the event function, you can get value of the clicked button and check it for its value.

Or you can pass clicked el into the function :

```
document.querySelector('button class').on('click', function(el) { 

           var value = el.value;

           if(value === 'something') {
               el.style.display = 'none'
           }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not straight forward, Do you want to hide the button whose value is "RESET"?

Comment: yes exactly. is there any way with considering only its value ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. Is this what you mean?

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("mat-button-wrapper");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].style.display = "none";
  console.log("Hidden: " + elements[i]);
}
```

Comment: actually i want to hide this button. but i am not able to hide this  with help of Class because this same class are using in other buttons i have

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to hide this button:

```
<button class="mat-raised-button mat-primary" color="primary" mat-raised-button="">
    <span class="mat-button-wrapper">RESET</span>
    <div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple=""></div>
    <div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div>
</button>
```

because it contains the word `RESET`

You can use the following:

```
// Get all relevant buttons
let myButtons = [...document.getElementsByClassName('mat-raised-button')];

// Cycle through buttons
myButtons.forEach((button) => {

  let matButtonWrapper = button.getElementsByClassName('mat-button-wrapper')[0];

  // Execute actions according to the mat-button-wrapper text
  switch(matButtonWrapper.textContent) {

    case ('RESET') : button.style.opacity = '0'; break;
    // case ('Another word here') : actions here; break;
    // case ('Another word here') : actions here; break;
    // case ('Another word here') : actions here; break;
    // case ('Another word here') : actions here; break;
  }

});
```